# Sharing ResourceBundle across web applications

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, localization, resourcebundle

Is it possible to access the message resources from one spring web application to another spring web application?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation while loading the properties file as a email setup. We did it by placing the file at a common place referred it in 2 applications by specifying the complete file path.

```
<bean id="mailProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location" value="file:/share/mail/config/mail.properties" />

</bean>
```

I think, you can do it in a similar way as follows

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basename" value="file:/common_place_for_/messages" />
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Comment: Hi, the path that is given in a "baseName", is it relative? and if yes, what is the base path then?

Comment: Hello,Haven't heard of `base path`. You can see,how the resources are loaded in spring -[here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/7795-messagesource-with-external-property-file). Should answer your questions